# How to make Windows file explorer show full dates for files - including year?

Tags: windows, windows-10

In Windows, is there **any** way to display the **full** creation or modification dates for files, **including a year**, without having to open the file properties? It could be either in the file info tooltip or the file details in folders. Please see the screenshot:

[image: Date modified and Date created]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the **Control Panel**, select **Language**, and then select the **Change date, time, or number formats**. From the <kbd>**`Formats`**</kbd> tab, select the <kbd>**`Additional settings`**</kbd> option. Go to the <kbd>**`Date`**</kbd> tab from there and adjust the **Short Date** drop down accordingly for your needs to show the year.

[image]

Comment: I know this comments section is not intended for thanking but I can't vote here yet and I need to tell you how grateful I am for you prompt and perfect answer, so - thank you!

Comment: @JosefH. No worries, that's what we're here for... to all help each other if and when we can. I'm glad I was able to help you get your issue resolved.