# How to find the day on which the file was created in Windows?

Tags: windows-10

By default, I can see the date and time on which the file was created.

However, I also want the day along with the date and time. How do I get that?

Also is it possible to display the week-day in the file explorer itself? i.e I would like the file explorer to show something like `12-10-2020 Monday 03:00PM`

Answer (score 2):

You can show the "creation date" that is stored for files in the Windows Explorer easily:

Switch Windows Explorer to column view, right click a column header and and in the context menu that pops up select "Creation Date" for enabling the additional column.

Note that this setting is folder-specific. Therefore if you open a different folder in Explorer you again have to add the Creation Date column for that folder.

Regarding the date format this can not be configured for the "Creation Date" column only. The date format used by the Windows Explorer is the one defined globally. If you want to change the date format you can do so in Windows settings as shown in this question: [How to make Windows file explorer show full dates for files - including year?](https://superuser.com/q/1180157/62676)

If you don't want that the only alternative would be installing a Windows Shell-extension that add an custom column showing the file creation date in the format you have in mind. Unfortunately I don't know such a shell extension that would fit your needs. If you have programming experience you could develop a simple shell extension on your own.

Comment: I've told that I need the Day of creation, like Monday, Tuesday, etc. I can see the Date and Time. What I need is the Day.

Comment: @SathvikKS Then your question is a bit inprecise. The "day" is usally the date when a file has been created (without time). What you want is the "week day". If you want this you have to write it exactly this way or give an example so that everybody can understand it.

Comment: I hope the question is precise now.

Comment: @SathvikKS See my updated answer.